# Can Screen Lock on iOS Android devices Log-out someone in an App

Tags: ios, authentication, locking, screen

A knowledge question about screen-lock and log-out.
We have a student / teacher interactive website where student logs-in to answer questions etc. A few days ago a very simple iOS App was developed that takes the student to the website login page. It does this, of course, in a rimless, app style screen; the website operates within the app screen.

I'm being told that when the Screen-Lock kicks in or they switch to another app and / or browser the students log-in session ends so that when they return to the app screen they have to log in again. My thoughts is that this might not be so. Any comments?

Comment: I suggest you look more into iOS application background states
https://hackernoon.com/application-life-cycle-in-ios-12b6ba6af78b

Comment: Thanks for the link. Appreciated but I'm only a spectator on the sidelines. Even though I have had a computer in front of me since the early 90's I know just enough to be dangerous. I did read the link page; it gave me a headache :-)